# Reference request: Parkinson's disease book

Tags: neuroscience, motor

I am about start a project on computational modelling of basal ganglia in the context of motor problems in Parkinson's disease. My background is mostly on computational side (and some neuroscience too) and I know relatively little about medicine. So I would like to extend my knowledge of the Parkinson-related medical science, so that I see not only separate puzzle pieces.

Could somebody suggest a recent book on Parkinsons's disease from medical perspective (and the more fundamental systems neuroscience it contains, the better)? I am more interested in motor symptoms and cognitive problems, as well as their treatments.
To emphasize, I am NOT looking for a book on computational approaches to BG/Parkinson's, I really want to know what neurologists think.

I have already posted [this question on medical SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/reference-request-parkinsons-disease-book) but I was redirected here.

Comment: I believe it is on topic here. I'm not certain who Carey talked to to say it isn't. I do agree this is not a [tag:reference-request], as it is not a concrete paper/book you have in mind. I feel what you are after is narrow enough. Even though it might attract subjective answers, I don't expect an infinite list of appropriate suggestions. If you want it to stick around here, you should likely delete the post on the other site.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I am confused now -- there are two reputable members who tell me opposite things -- who should I believe? Maybe it would be better if I just keep both questions for a while, then copy the answers, delete the one that have received less attention and then put all the answers in one place?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am also a bit confused by this . Given the circumstances, I believe it is fair if you wait on deciding which one to delete until you receive an answer on either, or in case the question would be put on hold.

Comment: Crossposting questions is discouraged, because people on both fronts may try to improve your question, which is a waste of effort. I'm putting it on hold therefore.